# Press pageup/pagedown after press esc when use vim in tmux

Tags: vim, tmux

When I Press pageup/pagedown after press esc when use vim in tmux, it will lower-case/upper-case the three characters after current cursor, is there any way to fix it?
thanks.

Comment: Yes. Don't press `pageup`/`pagedown` after pressing `esc`. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit of a non-answer, but don't!

Using arrow keys and special keys like <kbd>Home</kbd>, <kbd>End</kbd>, etc. is generally discouraged. In addition to the speed loss of moving your hands off the home row, there are often side effects like the ones you're seeing now.

Instead, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>b</kbd> to go forward and backward a page (same effect as <kbd>Page Down</kbd>/<kbd>PageUp</kbd>).

Alternatively, you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>u</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> to go up and down with smaller jumps.

Answer (score 2):

You may remap case-changing key or just disable it:

```
if &term =~ '^screen'
  " disable case-changing command to fix esc-esc-pagedown misbehavior.
  map ~ <Nop>
endif
```

Answer (score 1):

Specifically, the page-up key will send a sequence of characters, not a single character, to the input stream, which must then be interpeted. That sequence might be something like "^[[5~" (escape [ 5 ~), which means vim sees the ~ and performs its case-changing behavior.